# Adding data to hash inside a loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an OpenStruct `@dataos` with different values from a loop `[7,15,30, 60, 120].each do |num|`, but I got only the last one. Is there a method to add to my current hash `hashsproducts` and then fill the OpenStruct? Here is my code:

```
@dataos = OpenStruct.new()
[7,15,30, 60, 120].each do |num| 
  products = Product.where(:id => prod.id).sort_by(&:date_for).take(num)   
  hashsproducts = ({
    "series-#{num}" => get_data(products, :field1, 1.minute.to_f, 50),
    "collects-#{num}" => get_data(products, :field2, 1, 48),
    .…
    ….
  })
  @dataos = (hashscores)       
end
p "********** #{@dataos} *********************************************************"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting hashsproducts each time in the loop.

Try this

```
hashsproducts = {}
[7, 15, 30, 60, 120].each do |num|
  products = Product.where(:id => prod.id).sort_by(&:date_for).take(num)   
  hashsproducts["series-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field1, 1.minute.to_f, 50)
  hashsproducts["collects-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field2, 1, 48)
end

@dataos = OpenStruct.new(hashsproducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You **need a key for each product** otherwise you should use an array of hashes.

Try this for hash with product keys:

```
hashsproducts = {}
[7, 15, 30, 60, 120].each do |num|
  products = Product.where(:id => prod.id).sort_by(&:date_for).take(num)
  hashproducts[num]= {}
  hashsproducts[num]["series-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field1, 1.minute.to_f, 50)
  hashsproducts[num]["collects-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field2, 1, 48)
end

@dataos = OpenStruct.new(hashsproducts)
```

Or this for array of hashes:

```
hashsproducts = {}
result = []
[7, 15, 30, 60, 120].each do |num|
  products = Product.where(:id => prod.id).sort_by(&:date_for).take(num)
  hashsproducts["series-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field1, 1.minute.to_f, 50)
  hashsproducts["collects-#{num}"] = get_data(products, :field2, 1, 48)
  result << hashproducts
end
```